# Merging 2 tables with same columns but different select value

Tags: sql-server, join

Can someone suggest how to merge these 2 resultsets/tables below so that the expected output can be achieve.

- `currentPrice` value will take priority from `PriceChangedTable`, and if not available from `StatusChangedTable`. Null is a valid value.
- `status` value will take priority from `StatusChangedTable`, and if not available from `PriceChangedTable`

PriceChangedTable:

```
    Id  vehicle     currentPrice    status
    ---------------------------------------------
    1   toyota      50000           Available
    2   nisaan      null            Available
    3   bmw         30000           Pending
```

StatusChangedTable:

```
    Id  vehicle     currentPrice    status
    ---------------------------------------------
    1   toyota      null            NotAvailable
    3   bmw         40000           NotAvailable
    4   dodge       50000           Pending
```

Output from merging the above 2 tables:

```
    Id  vehicle     currentPrice    status
    ---------------------------------------------
    1   toyota      50000           NotAvailable
    2   nisaan      null            Available
    3   bmw         30000           NotAvailable
    4   dodge       50000           Pending
```

Please don't judge table designing skills.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return the expected output:

```sql
select
    p.Id
    ,p.vehicle
    ,p.currentPrice
    -- status value priority 1) StatusChangedTable, 2) PriceChangedTable
    ,case when s.Id is not null then s.status else p.status end as status
from PriceChangedTable p
left join StatusChangedTable s on p.Id = s.Id
union
select
    s.Id
    ,s.vehicle
    -- currentPrice value priority 1) PriceChangedTable, 2) StatusChangedTable
    ,case when p.Id is not null then p.currentPrice else s.currentPrice end as currentPrice
    ,s.status
from StatusChangedTable s
left join PriceChangedTable p on p.Id = s.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

try with other sample data,

```
SELECT isnull(pc.Id, sc.id) id
    ,isnull(pc.vehicle, sc.vehicle) vehicle
    ,isnull(pc.currentPrice, sc.currentPrice) currentPrice
    ,isnull(sc.[status], pc.[status]) [status]
FROM @PriceChnagedTable PC
FULL OUTER JOIN @StatusChangedTable SC ON pc.id = sc.Id
```